# Maven replacer plugin cannot find file

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I want to use `maven replacer plugin` in order to change content of one of the files in target directory. Here is my plugin definition:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>replace</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <file>target\${project.`enter code here`artifactId}-${project.version}\WEB-INF\classes\config\config-core.properties</file>
        <replacements>
            <replacement>
                <token>oneVal</token>
                <value>replaceWith</value>
            </replacement>
        </replacements>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I run **maven command mvn clean package** I got an error that says:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin:replacer:1.5.1:replace (default) on project : File 'C:\dev\somePath\target\-\WEB-INF\classes\config\config-core.properties' does not exist -> [Help 1]

I guess it happens because I try to replace file before it gets to target folder. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that your `replacer plugin` is running between the `clean and package phase`. Ideally it should run after once the package phase is completed , as in after clean phase target folder is not available , hence it is complaining for missing file.

Change the phase to package and then try it should work.

```
 <phase>package</phase>
```

Comment: My typo. There was no // in original error message. Fixed the question

Comment: Doesn't work for me - it runs after the assembly and jar plugins, but I want it to run in between.  Maven. Wasting so much time.

Comment: @saurav - The problem of using it at package phase is that it makes to the target eploded package folder but it won't be included in the final WAR package inside target folder that has already been generated when the replacer runs. So this is not a valid solution to the problem.